# how to access a shared folder in onedrive without login

Tags: graph, onedrive

I have an onedrive for business account. I shared a folder to anyone that anyone use can view or edit the folder.

So anyone can enter this folder, view the files or upload files or edit the existing files.

but I want to access this folder using microsfot graph APIs without login any user(because all the operations do not need to login).
in the microsoft graph API document, all the accesses need an access token.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the sharing link for the resource in question you can use the [Shares API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to encode the sharing link in a request so that it is essentially used as the authentication.

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you for your answer. I tested the APIs you recommend. I found that logged in account A can access the shared folder from account B. but it does not work when the accounts is onedrive for business.

Comment: And I did't find the API which create folder or upload file using the sharing link. Is it forbidden?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't speak to your exact situation, this is what worked for me when trying to send file by MMS with Twilio in Power Automate:

Since OneDrive share links, even with "Direct" type selected, do not end in [file name with extension] like Azure File Share links do, I reasoned that the Azure File Share method would work when OneDrive would not. Now, even with Azure File Share links the URL actually does not end in the file name and extension since you have to include the Query String after the extension. You have to get a Shared Access Signature for the folder or file you want to share, and this puts some kind of token in the URL (URI more specifically?) which enables access to the file.

This won't help you much if you don't have an Azure file share and don't feel like setting one up, although it's pretty easy, but maybe it would point us in the right direction!

There is no [file name with extension] in the OneDrive share link. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that happen. But it's rather easy to stand up an Azure storage account. I believe it's extremely cost-effective and you get a substantial free trial.

If you don't want to go the Azure route, I suggest you find some way of generating a link that includes the file name and extension. This seems to be a requirement for Twilio MMS. Maybe Graph API is similar? OneDrive share links did not work, presumably because they have some sort of redirection going on. They are not truly direct links to the file.

Anyway, this is all a different use case then your scenario, but I think it may help you! Maybe OneDrive does not have the capability you need? But I'm pretty sure Azure does.